# Order of `Stack<T>` in .NET

Tags: .net, stack

Is there a defined order for a `Stack<T>` when enumerating? Is it guaranteed to take the bottom (first inserted) first or the top (last inserted)? The [documentation for `GetEnumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfw8w9at(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Stack<T>.Enumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2bb46cs(v=vs.110).aspx) both do not clearly specify other than it starts before the "first element", which is a bit ambiguous in the case of a `Stack<T>`.

Comment: It depends, if the documentation is actually *documenting* the order, then the example here - https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1.getenumerator?view=netframework-4.7.2 - shows that the order is from top to bottom (ie. last pushed to first pushed).

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen yea examples can be deceiving.

Comment: Enumeration isn't logically defined for stacks, or for queues, so the order of enumeration is not defined. The fact that a library even allows you to "see" beyond the "next" or "top" item in a stack is strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

The GetEnumerator is probably implemented uniquely for Stack.  Let's see:

from https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/stack.cs

```
    // Pushes an item to the top of the stack.
    // 
    /// <include file='doc\Stack.uex' path='docs/doc[@for="Stack.Push"]/*' />
    public void Push(T item) {
        if (_size == _array.Length) {
            T[] newArray = new T[(_array.Length == 0) ? _defaultCapacity : 2*_array.Length];
            Array.Copy(_array, 0, newArray, 0, _size);
            _array = newArray;
        }
        _array[_size++] = item;
        _version++;
    }
```

and

```
    // Returns an IEnumerator for this Stack.
    /// <include file='doc\Stack.uex' path='docs/doc[@for="Stack.GetEnumerator"]/*' />
    public Enumerator GetEnumerator() {
        return new Enumerator(this);
    }
```

..so it looks like the last in is the last in the enumerator, the first one pushed will be the first one out in a foreach.  I couldn't see where the `return new Enumerator(this)` has the `this` auto-boxed for the enumerator ctor, but hey, I'm guessing it's the internal array.

Comment: if it isn't documented, it isn't guaranteed. i'm looking for more than reference source.

Comment: You could maybe write a unit test or two to try a few sequences of Push, Pop, etc's?  Some empirical evidence, if you like.  Also, I'd thought the Reference Source to be the ultimate documentation...  Why would you think otherwise?